# What does this dialog from Mad Men mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the TV series "Mad Men" I'm currently watching, a man is conducting a job interview with two young males (person 1 and person 2) in episode 1 of season 2 ("For Those Who Think Young") starting at about 32:47. During that interview, the following dialog takes place:

> Interviewer: "Are you married?
>   Person 1: Uh, that's why we're on the purpose.
>   Person 2: He's right. We haven't settled down yet.
>   Interviewer: [*pauses*] So, again, you both did everything together, and yet you get paid more [*pointing to person 2*].

I don't understand this dialog at all. **What does "That's why we're on the purpose" mean?**

I looked up "purpose" in the wiktionary, but couldn't find anything relevant. **And what does this have to do with their pay?** Or is the interviewer just changing the topic?

Edit: I should add that person 1 is not a native speaker.

Comment: This makes so little sense to me that I think it must have been mistranscribed.

Comment: It's not mistranscribed, but it is gibberish. :)   Not one of the guy's lines makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "That's why we're on the purpose" mean?

It means this character does not speak standard English. He has a strong accent and often makes mistakes speaking English.

> And what does this have to do with their pay?

The interviewer thinks that the two guys are going to work together to do the work of one person, and expect to both be paid.

Comment: Yep. Later in the interview Kurt says *Only when it's a distance* which doesn't make any sense either.

Answer (score 1):

To be **on the purpose** is nonsense. The other things said by this character are well-formed (e.g. "I get the distinct impression") but they have nothing to do with what's going on in the scene. It's rather like pulling the string on a talking doll.

These are not "mistakes". They're empty phrases.